# How to trim and process current url using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Let's say I have my current url as: https://example.com/test?id=W2FiY11beHl6XVsxMjNd .
The content after ?id is `[abc][xyz][123]` and is base64 encoded.

I want to process the current url so the content on the page looks like:

```
<div class="">abc</div>
<div class="">xyz</div>
<div class="">123</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with jquery or whatever?

Comment: if the values are within [] then you can use regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: *"The content after ?id is [abc][xyz][123] and is base64 encoded."* - Well... decode it, split it up, put it in your HTML. There is no question in this post (other than "please write this for me ...", and that's not a question)

Comment: `Is there a way to do this with jquery or whatever?` ? yes, there is a way to do this with jquery or whatever. DOes this answer help you or whatever ?

Comment: i don't know in jquery is there a function to decode base64 or do we have to use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
const urlString = `https://example.com/test?id=W2FiY11beHl6XVsxMjNd` // The content after ?id is [abc][xyz][123] and is base64 encoded.

const url = new URL(urlString); // this could be location.href
const id = url.searchParams.get("id"); // get the ID
const html = [...atob(id).matchAll(/\[(\w+)\]/g)] // get the [...][...][...]
  .map(item => `<div class="">${item[1]}</div>`)  // map them to divs
  .join(""); // join with empty string
document.body.innerHTML += html; // do whatever you need with the HTML string
```

**jQuery**

```js
const urlString = `https://example.com/test?id=W2FiY11beHl6XVsxMjNd` // The content after ?id is [abc][xyz][123] and is base64 encoded.

const url = new URL(urlString); // this could be location.href
const id = url.searchParams.get("id"); // get the ID
const html = [...atob(id).matchAll(/\[(\w+)\]/g)] // get the [...][...][...]
  .map(item => `<div class="">${item[1]}</div>`) // map them to divs
  .join(""); // join with empty string
$("body").append(html); // do whatever you need with the HTML string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```